# Problem with Starting MySQL Server after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: mysql

I have a problem to start MySQL after an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 (MySQL 5.7 to 8). When I tried to start the mysql service kit stops at "Starting MySQL Community Server...".

```
USER@SERVER:~$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2020-08-19 11:38:13 CEST; 576ms ago
    Process: 18006 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 18014 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 1110)
     Memory: 261.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─18014 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Aug 19 11:38:13 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

The journal gives me back the following.

```
USER@SERVER:~$ journalctl -xe


--
-- The job identifier is 24060.
Aug 19 11:38:17 boris-dev systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 19 11:38:17 boris-dev systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 19 11:38:17 boris-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 24060 and the job result is failed.
Aug 19 11:38:17 boris-dev systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 139.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 19 11:38:17 boris-dev systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 24126 and the job result is done.
Aug 19 11:38:17 boris-dev systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 24126.
```

There are a few databases and it would be nice to keep them, but not necessary.

Any idea what's best to do?

Thanks in advance

Bo

Comment: You can also check `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.
To backup mysql databases you could do `rsync -av /var/lib/mysql/ /var/lib/mysql-bak/`. You could then `apt purge mysql-server` and `apt install mysql-server` to reinstall. In my experience purge didn't remove `/var/lib/mysql/*` so I didn't need to restore the backup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem upgrading a server from Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. The solution was to remove two lines from the configuration file.

File: /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment out:

#query_cache_limit      = 1M

#query_cache_size        = 16M

The server upgrade involves upgrading to MySQL 8 in which some variables are deprecated including query_cache_limit and query_cache_size.

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/1042328/1006560